# django1.8.4 models reverse order can't work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.8

[image]

I am using python2.7, django1.8.4, MySQL.

I have tried the following:
views:

```
messages=Message.objects.all().order_by('time').reverse()
messages=Message.objects.all().order_by('-time')
```

models:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    body=models.TextField(blank=True)
    time=models.DateField(timezone.now,blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.title)
```

and I use django shell to test:

```
>>> from main.models import Message
>>> messages=Message.objects.all()
>>> messages

[<Message: 7ht>, <Message: >, <Message: fvdsv>, <Message: dddddddd>, <Message: dddddddd>, <Message: dddddddd>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: >, <Message: >, <Message: >, <Message: >, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>]

>>> messages=Message.objects.order_by("time")
>>> messages

[<Message: 7ht>, <Message: >, <Message: fvdsv>, <Message: dddddddd>, <Message: dddddddd>, <Message: dddddddd>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: >, <Message: >, <Message: >, <Message: >, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>]

>>> messages.reverse()

[<Message: 7ht>, <Message: >, <Message: fvdsv>, <Message: dddddddd>, <Message: dddddddd>, <Message: dddddddd>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: >, <Message: >, <Message: >, <Message: >, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>, <Message: sssssssssss>]
```

Comment: How is it not working? What is it returning instead? Can you show the code for your model? There's a lot you left out in your question.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: class Message(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    body=models.TextField(blank=True)
    time=models.DateField(timezone.now,blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.title)

Comment: it can't  reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

I am foolish....

```
time=models.DateField(timezone.now,blank=True,null=True)
```

should be:

```
time=models.DateTimeField(timezone.now,blank=True,null=True)
```